# How to run an Applescript that will click and open all links on a web page?

Tags: hyperlink, automation, click, applescript

I'm trying to write a script that will automatically open a webpage http://www.legislation.gov.uk/new/uksi and then click on all the links in the table "All New Legislation".

So far I've managed to get it to open the page but no luck with clicking.

Here's my script so far:

```
activate application "Safari"
open location "http://www.legislation.gov.uk/new/uksi"

to clickID()
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById(id=per).click();" in document 1
end tell
```

Comment: Your click instruction just click on id=per which is just the body of the page. so nothing happens. I guess you wan too click on specific button and that's the element you must address to click on via the do java script instruction.

Comment: You said, "...and then click on all the links contained on that page.", you do seriously mean  "all the links contained on that page", including Home, Understanding Legislation, EU Legislation and UK Law, Browse Legislation, Changes To Legislation, Search Legislation, Advanced Search, Today, 6th Jan, 27th Dec, 24th Dec, 23rd Dec, 20th Dec, 19th Dec, 18th Dec, 17th Dec,16th Dec, Help, About Us, Site Map, Accessibility, Contact Us, Privacy Notice, Cookies, etc.?

Comment: I see you have updated the question after my previous comment to include "and then click on all the links in the table "All New Legislation".", however I suspect you do not want every link under **All New Legislation** clicked or do you? Do you really want the links for e.g. United Kingdom, Scotland, Wales, Northern Ireland, and if exists UK Statutory Instruments, Scotland Statutory Instruments, Wales Statutory Instruments, Northern Ireland Statutory Instruments, or do you just want the links of the actual new legislation? **You really need to be explicit and specific about what you want!**

Comment: That said, I think you should forget about clicking on the links to the actual new legislation and instead focus on getting a _list_ **URLs** of the _target links_ to open in new tabs. I believe that is a better/easier way to go to achieve the goal. Assuming it's just the links of the actual new legislation, I noticed a pattern on these **URLs** that makes them easily searchable from a _list_ of all **URLs** on the page. I've posted an answer using this approach.

Answer (score 0):

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will open the `targetURL` in a new **Safari** *window*, wait for the *page* to finish loading, retrieve all **URLs** on the *target page*, search them for **URLs** pointing the various **Statutory Instruments** published today, and then open each one in a new *tab* of the same *window* the `targetURL` was opened.

```
set targetURL to "http://www.legislation.gov.uk/new/uksi"
set theseURLs to {}
set grepSearchPattern to ".*\\.uk/uksi/.*\\|.*\\.uk/ssi/.*\\|.*\\.uk/wsi/.*\\|.*\\.uk/nisi/.*"
set jsStatements to "var a = document.links; var x = ''; var i; for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { x = x + a[i].href + '|'; };"

tell application "Safari"
    make new document with properties {URL:targetURL}
    activate
end tell

tell application "System Events"
    repeat until exists ¬
        (buttons of UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
            process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
        delay 1
    end repeat
end tell

tell application "Safari"
    set allURLs to (do JavaScript jsStatements in document 1)
end tell

try
    set theseURLs to paragraphs of (do shell script "tr '|' '\\12' <<< " & ¬
        allURLs's quoted form & " | grep " & grepSearchPattern's quoted form)
end try

if (length of theseURLs) is greater than 0 then
    tell application "Safari" to tell front window
        repeat with thisURL in theseURLs
            set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:thisURL})
        end repeat
        set current tab to first tab
    end tell
else
    display dialog "    Nothing published on this date." buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 with title "All New Legislation" with icon note
end if
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal/vertical scroll to see full code.</sup>

**Notes:**

- The `do JavaScript`<sup>1</sup> *command* create a *pipe* delimited *string* of all **URLs** on the page of the `targetURL`.
- The `do shell script` *command* takes the *pipe* delimited *string* of all **URLs** and replaces the *pipe* characters with *newline* characters, using `tr`, so `grep` can return the **URLs** that match the `grepSearchPattern`.
- <sub>The `grepSearchPattern` *variable* currently only searches for **Statutory Instruments**, as I assume that is all that will show under **All New Legislation** on the *page* the `targetURL` opens to, because of `/new/uksi` in the `targetURL`, and what I've observed at that **URL** since you posted the question. If you also want *links* for other types of legislation, the `grepSearchPattern` *variable* can be adjusted to accommodate.</sub>
- <sup>1</sup> Using the `do JavaScript` *command* requires **Allow JavaScript from Apple Events** to be checked on the **Safari** > **Develop** menu, which is hidden by default and can be shown by checking **[√] Show Develop menu in menu bar** in: **Safari** > **Preferences…** > **Advanced**
  If you are not allowed to enable that setting, the **URLs** can be collected for processing in another manner, however it uses the `lynx` third party utility.

---

**Opening the *links* without the use of the `do JavaScript` *command*:**

The following *example* **AppleScript** *code* will use `lynx` to retrieve the **URLs** from the `targetURL`, search them for **URLs** pointing the various **Statutory Instruments** published today, and if some have been published will open the `targetURL` in a new **Safari** *window*, wait for the *page* to finish loading, and then open each one in a new *tab* of the same *window* the `targetURL` was opened.

```
set targetURL to "http://www.legislation.gov.uk/new/uksi"
set theseURLs to {}
set lynxCommand to "/usr/local/bin/lynx --dump -listonly -nonumbers -hiddenlinks=ignore"
set grepSearchPattern to ".*\\.uk/uksi/.*\\|.*\\.uk/ssi/.*\\|.*\\.uk/wsi/.*\\|.*\\.uk/nisi/.*"

try
    set theseURLs to paragraphs of ¬
        (do shell script lynxCommand & space & targetURL's quoted form & ¬
            " | grep " & grepSearchPattern's quoted form)
end try

if (length of theseURLs) is greater than 0 then
    tell application "Safari"
        make new document with properties {URL:targetURL}
        activate
    end tell
    tell application "System Events"
        repeat until exists ¬
            (buttons of UI elements of groups of toolbar 1 of window 1 of ¬
                process "Safari" whose name = "Reload this page")
            delay 1
        end repeat
    end tell
    tell application "Safari" to tell front window
        repeat with thisURL in theseURLs
            set current tab to (make new tab with properties {URL:thisURL})
        end repeat
        set current tab to first tab
    end tell
else
    display dialog "    Nothing published on this date." buttons {"OK"} ¬
        default button 1 with title "All New Legislation" with icon note
end if
```

<sup>Hint: Mouse over and horizontal/vertical scroll to see full code.</sup>

**Notes:**

- In the `lynxCommand` *variable*, change `/usr/local/bin/lynx` to the appropriate `/path/to/lynx`. `lynx` can be installed using **Homebrew**
- <sub>The `grepSearchPattern` *variable* currently only searches for **Statutory Instruments**, as I assume that is all that will show under **All New Legislation** on the *page* the `targetURL` opens to, because of `/new/uksi` in the `targetURL`, and what I've observed at that **URL** since you posted the question. If you also want *links* for other types of legislation, the `grepSearchPattern` *variable* can be adjusted to accommodate.</sub>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1).</sub>